# How to resolve MigrationFailedException in Liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying to use Liquibase in my application. I have created a changelog.yaml as -

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: test_file.sql
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      preConditions:
        - onFail: MARK_RAN
        - onError: CONTINUE
        - sqlCheck:
            expectedResult: 0
            sql: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<TABLE_NAME>'"
```

I am still receiving MigrationFailedException as the table is already present in the database. Please suggest if the syntax of the yaml is incorrect.

Comment: i think the issues is there in your sql file, not on this yaml file.